# android studio emulator display bug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

After updating to Android Studio to version 2.0 my emulator do not work correctly.

[image: Emulator image]

The properties:
[image: The properties]

Problem is duplicated on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.

Full reinstall of Android Studio, SDK, AVD did not help.

================================ PART 2 ================================

Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager show this:

[SDK Manager from Android Studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxokC.png)

Standalone SDK Manager:

[Standalone SDK Manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP5PQ.png)

and SDK Platform API 10 "Not compatible with Windows"

Comment: select `nexus_6`  or your `QVGA (ADP2)` in custom skin definition SECTION .

Comment: Looks like the problem is in missing android-10 in sdk\platforms

Answer (score 0):

After updating to Android Studio 2.1 the bug is gone